# New subcategory, adding products - how do I filter by configurable product only?

Tags: configurable-product, category, category-products

we set-up a new category

and after that we add products

but the problem is that we *only* need to select the configurable products

the problem is that the category products selector shows *all* product types

This is costing us so much time to go through rows and rows of data selecting the configurbale type

How can this be done faster?

[image]

Comment: I see that you are using the custimizable grid extension. You should be able to add the product type as a column in the grid.

Comment: ahum. Sorry about that one. Yes ofcourse! (we just installed the extension - did not expect to see it here). WOOHOO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @Marius

[Install customizable grid extension](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids)

and add filter

Comment: Could you maybe provide the code for adding filters?

Comment: There is no code. It is config.

Comment: Oh cool so this is really easy to deal with

Comment: if you add the extension. It is easy